# Obj-C can't parse HTML

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xpath, hpple

I am parsing some HTML, and I keep getting that the node is nil, when I know its not and I have evaluated the same xPath string in both Safari and Chrome and it takes me where I want here is the code.

In `viewDidLoad`

```
self.url = @"https://rpi.sodexomyway.com/dining-choices/res/index.html";
[self getMenuItems:self.url];
```

In `getMenuItems:`

```
//I just get the data aSync
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    [self getData:data];

}];
```

In `getData:`

```
TFHpple *Parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:factData];

NSString *planString = @"/html[@class='cufon-active cufon-ready']/body/div[@id='main-content']/div[@id='subs-container']/div[@class='main-corners']/div[@class='column-66 float-left']/div[@class='pane-accord']/div[@id='hideinse']/div[@id='accordion_23471']/div[@id='ui-accordion-accordion_23471-panel-1']/span/p[3]";
NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [Parser searchWithXPathQuery:planString];

NSLog(@"tut: %@", tutorialsNodes);

for (TFHppleElement *element in tutorialsNodes) {

    NSLog(@"element: %@", [element text]);

}
```

But `tutorialsNodes` comes back as an empty array and Im not sure why, you can go to the site in this question and put that xPath in the console and you get this text `Tuesday: 7:30a - 7:30p` . But it is not being returned where is my code going wrong?

Why is the array nil?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Have you verified that `factData` has the actual XML you expect to be getting?

Comment: @rmaddy okay I can get the xml string, but what is a good way to check the xml returned to the one on the web? I can't go line by line its way to long?

Comment: @rmaddy is there a way to check the downloaded xml?

Comment: You could convert the data to an `NSString` and log the string.